# HttpRequestMessageProperty in netcoreapp2.0 requered System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.1.2.0 instead System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.4.0.0

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a webapi service C# + net core 2.0. It calls wcf and returns data to client. Everything worked well, there were a lot of requests type of HTTP HEAD without credentials to WCF. 
I've read an [article](http://managedmonkey.blogspot.ru/2012/12/operationcontextscope-and-asyncawait.html).
I've tryed to add

```
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
                {
                    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                    httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +
                    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" +
                    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] =
                       httpRequestProperty;
                    var homerResultTask = client.getClientCreditsAsync(new getClientCreditsRequest(cuid));
                    homerResultTask.Wait();
                    homerResult = homerResultTask.Result;
                }
```

unstead of simple call method

```
var homerResultTask = client.getClientCreditsAsync(new getClientCreditsRequest(cuid));
                    homerResultTask.Wait();
```

At my local machine and development environment everything works well.
But in production environment I have en error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

In my project.csproj :

```
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.0" />
```

And there are no links to System.ServiceModel.Http with version 4.1.2. But when I see code of System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty
 from metadata in Visual Studio Code, I see:

```
#region Assembly System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

// System.ServiceModel.Http.dll

When I publish my project with "dotnet publish -c release" I se only 1 file : it's System.ServiceModel.Http version 4.4.0. How can I have 2 diffenet version of 1 dll on production environment?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple: there was no sdk on production server, only runtime. After installing https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=53321 the library System.ServiceModel.Http with public token key=b03f5f7f11d50a3aappered on production server. Now everything works correctly